# How to make ghost in pacman move slower? Python

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

I'm writing pacman in pygame. I've got a problem with ghost moving. It is moving too fast. When it moves by speed 1, it is very fast. When the speed is 0.1, my code doesn't work.

Here is the ghost movement code:

```
#GHOST MOVE
move_list = ['right', 'left', 'up', 'down']
move_chise = random.choice(move_list)
if move_chise == 'right':
    while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
        ghost.rect.x += speed
    ghost.rect.x -= 2
elif move_chise == 'left':
    while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
        ghost.rect.x -= speed
    ghost.rect.x += 2
elif move_chise == 'up':
    while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
        ghost.rect.y -= speed
    ghost.rect.y += 2
elif move_chise == 'down':
    while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
        ghost.rect.y += speed
    ghost.rect.y -= 2
```

Here is my all code:

```
import random
from pygame import *

animCount = 0

class GameSprite(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player_image, player_x, player_y, size_x, size_y, player_speed):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = transform.scale(image.load(player_image), (size_x, size_y))
        self.speed = player_speed
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = player_x
        self.rect.y = player_y
    def show(player):
        window.blit(player.image, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y))
class Hero(GameSprite):
    def update(player):
        print('fff')
class Enemy(GameSprite):
    def move(self):
        pass
class Wall(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color1, color2, color3, wall_x, wall_y, wall_width, wall_height):
        super().__init__()
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.color3 = color3
        self.width = wall_width
        self.height = wall_height
        self.image = Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.image.fill((color1, color2, color3))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = wall_x
        self.rect.y = wall_y
    def draw_wall(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
class Coins_s(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color1, color2, color3, wall_x, wall_y, wall_width, wall_height):
        super().__init__()
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.color3 = color3
        self.width = wall_width
        self.height = wall_height
        self.image = Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.image.fill((color1, color2, color3))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = wall_x
        self.rect.y = wall_y
    def draw_wall(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
coins = sprite.Group()

win_height = 700
win_width = 700
window = display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
display.set_caption('Pacman Game')
clock = time.Clock()

back = transform.scale(image.load('photo_2022-06-05_21-28-54.jpg'), (700, 700))
player = Hero('photo_2022-06-05_20-54-50.jpg', 10, 309, 15, 15, 2)
ghost = Enemy('photo_2022-06-05_20-56-46.jpg', 350, 309, 20, 25, 2)

w1 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 0, 700, 31)
w2 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 20, 31, 210)
w3 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 200, 145, 31)
w4 = Wall(169,169,169, 115, 200, 31, 95)
w5 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 270, 145, 31)
w7 = Wall(169,169,169, 670, 20, 31, 210)
w8 = Wall(169,169,169, 556, 200, 145, 31)
w9 = Wall(169,169,169, 556, 200, 31, 95)
w10 = Wall(169,169,169, 556, 270, 150, 31)
w11 = Wall(169,169,169, 335, 0, 31, 95)
w12 = Wall(169,169,169, 187, 70, 110, 31)
w13 = Wall(169,169,169, 406, 70, 110, 31)
w14 = Wall(169,169,169, 187, 470, 110, 31)
w15 = Wall(169,169,169, 406, 470, 110, 31)
w16 = Wall(169,169,169, 190, 335, 31, 95)
w17 = Wall(169,169,169, 485, 335, 31, 95)
w18 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 670, 700, 31)
w19 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 400, 31, 280)
w20 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 400, 145, 31)
w21 = Wall(169,169,169, 115, 340, 31, 70)
w22 = Wall(169,169,169, 0, 334, 145, 31)
w23 = Wall(169,169,169, 670, 400, 31, 280)
w24 = Wall(169,169,169, 556, 340, 31, 70)
w25 = Wall(169,169,169, 556, 334, 145, 31)
w26 = Wall(169,169,169, 556, 400, 150, 31)
w27 = Wall(169,169,169, 16, 531, 60, 31)
w28 = Wall(169,169,169, 624, 531, 60, 31)
w29 = Wall(169,169,169, 260, 340, 180, 31)
w30 = Wall(169,169,169, 260, 135, 180, 31)
w31 = Wall(169,169,169, 260, 531, 180, 31)
w32 = Wall(169,169,169, 260, 400, 180, 31)
w33 = Wall(169,169,169, 190, 135, 31, 160)
w34 = Wall(169,169,169, 335, 135, 31, 95)
w35 = Wall(169,169,169, 335, 405, 31, 95)
w36 = Wall(169,169,169, 335, 542, 31, 95)
w37 = Wall(169,169,169, 190, 535, 31, 95)
w38 = Wall(169,169,169, 485, 535, 31, 95)
w39 = Wall(169,169,169, 485, 135, 31, 160)
w40 = Wall(169,169,169, 75, 70, 70, 31)
w41 = Wall(169,169,169, 75, 133, 70, 31)
w42 = Wall(169,169,169, 555, 70, 70, 31)
w43 = Wall(169,169,169, 555, 133, 70, 31)
w44 = Wall(169,169,169, 555, 470, 70, 31)
w45 = Wall(169,169,169, 75, 470, 70, 31)
w46 = Wall(169,169,169, 115, 470, 31, 95)
w47 = Wall(169,169,169, 555, 470, 31, 95)
w48 = Wall(169,169,169, 75, 600, 220, 31)
w49 = Wall(169,169,169, 405, 600, 220, 31)
w50 = Wall(169,169,169, 215, 200, 85, 31)
w51 = Wall(169,169,169, 405, 200, 85, 31)
w52 = Wall(169,169,169, 260, 270, 30, 31)
w53 = Wall(169,169,169, 410, 270, 30, 31)
w54 = Wall(169,169,169, 260, 275, 31, 95)
w55 = Wall(169,169,169, 410, 275, 31, 95)

C1 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 130, 309, 5, 5)
C2 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 240, 309, 5, 5)
C3 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 340, 250, 5, 5)
C4 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 460, 309, 5, 5)
C5 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 570, 309, 5, 5)
C6 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 240, 180, 5, 5)
C7 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 460, 180, 5, 5)
C8 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 310, 111, 5, 5)
C9 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 390, 111, 5, 5)
C10 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 60, 180, 5, 5)
C11 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 640, 180, 5, 5)
C12 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 60, 50, 5, 5)
C13 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 640, 50, 5, 5)
C14 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 160, 409, 5, 5)
C15 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 240, 380, 5, 5)
C16 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 340, 380, 5, 5)
C17 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 460, 380, 5, 5)
C18 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 530, 409, 5, 5)
C19 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 460, 450, 5, 5)
C20 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 240, 450, 5, 5)
C21 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 390, 450, 5, 5)
C22 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 310, 450, 5, 5)
C23 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 630, 450, 5, 5)
C24 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 50, 450, 5, 5)
C25 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 600, 520, 5, 5)
C26 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 90, 520, 5, 5)
C27 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 530, 570, 5, 5)
C28 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 160, 570, 5, 5)
C29 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 60, 640, 5, 5)
C30 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 640, 640, 5, 5)
C31 = Coins_s(255,255,0, 350, 640, 5, 5)

coins.add(C1)
coins.add(C2)
coins.add(C3)
coins.add(C4)
coins.add(C5)
coins.add(C6)
coins.add(C7)
coins.add(C8)
coins.add(C9)
coins.add(C10)
coins.add(C11)
coins.add(C12)
coins.add(C13)
coins.add(C14)
coins.add(C15)
coins.add(C16)
coins.add(C17)
coins.add(C18)
coins.add(C19)
coins.add(C20)
coins.add(C21)
coins.add(C22)
coins.add(C23)
coins.add(C24)
coins.add(C25)
coins.add(C26)
coins.add(C27)
coins.add(C28)
coins.add(C29)
coins.add(C30)
coins.add(C31)

walls = [ w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w7, w8, w9,
                w10, w11, w12, w13, w14, w15, w16, w17, w18, w19, w20, w21, w22, w23, w24,
                w25, w26, w27, w28, w29, w30, w31, w32, w33, w34, w35, w36, w37, w38, w39,
                w40, w41, w42, w43, w44, w45, w46, w47, w48, w49, w50, w51, w52, w53, w54,
                w55]

finish = False
game = True

coins_count = 0
count = 0
speed = 1

while game:
    for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                exit()
    #GHOST MOVE
    move_list = ['right', 'left', 'up', 'down']
    move_chise = random.choice(move_list)
    if move_chise == 'right':
        while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.x += speed
        ghost.rect.x -= 2
    elif move_chise == 'left':
        while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.x -= speed
        ghost.rect.x += 2
    elif move_chise == 'up':
        while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.y -= speed
        ghost.rect.y += 2
    elif move_chise == 'down':
        while not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.y += speed
        ghost.rect.y -= 2
    #PACMAN MOVE
    side = 'None'
    keyPressed = key.get_pressed()
    if keyPressed[K_LEFT] and player.rect.x > 5:
        player.rect.x -= 2
        if sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False):
            side = 'Right'
        if side == 'Right':
            print(side)
            player.rect.x += 2
    if keyPressed[K_RIGHT] and player.rect.x < win_width - 40:
        player.rect.x += player.speed
        if sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False):
            side = 'Left'
        if side == 'Left':
            print(side)
            player.rect.x -= 2
    if keyPressed[K_UP] and player.rect.y > 5:
        player.rect.y -= player.speed
        if sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False):
            side = 'Down'
        if side == 'Down':
            print(side)
            player.rect.y += 2
    if keyPressed[K_DOWN] and player.rect.y < win_height - 40:
        player.rect.y += player.speed
        if sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False):
            side = 'Up'
        if side == 'Up':
            print(side)
            player.rect.y -= 2
    if player.rect.x == 660 and 300 < player.rect.y < 330:
            player.rect.x , player.rect.y = 10 ,308
    if sprite.spritecollide(player, coins, True):
        coins_count += 10
    if finish != True:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        for w in walls:
            w.draw_wall()
        coins.draw(window)
        player.show()
        ghost.show()
        display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Can you say what the problem is and how I can fix it?
This is how my game looks:

[image: My game]

Comment: _but when the speed is 0.1 my code is not working_ - HOW exactly it is not working? Do you get any error?

Comment: change `clock.tick(60)` to `clock.tick(30)` or to `clock.tick(120)`

Comment: Probably there is an issue while using floating numbers, I suggest you to check out [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). You could resolve by using `format()` or using directly integers

Comment: if you use `clock.tick(30)` then all will run half of current speed and then `speed = 1` will also work half slower. Eventually you should use `pygame.time` to execute move using time. And you if you want to use `0.1` then you have to remeber that screen use integer values and `0.1` can be converted to `0`. it may need to keep position as `float` in seprated variables and at the end convert to `int` to display it.

Comment: as in answer belowe; `while game` should be the only loop in code. Using `while` loop to detect collision you repeate it until it get collision - but this change value in variable but not image on screen. You should rather use `if` to check collsion only once in every `while game`

Comment: it would be simpler to do `walls = [ Wall(169,169,169, 0, 0, 700, 31), ....]` without variables `w1`, etc. Eventually you could keep it as list of tuples `walls_data = [(169,169,169, 0, 0, 700, 31), ....]` and use `for`-loop to convert it to list of walls `walls = [Wall(*data) for data in walls_data]`. And later you could read these tuples from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you use `while` to check collision - So, in every loop of `while Game` it repeats until it gets a collision. This changes the value ofthe variable but doesn't change the image on the screen.

In every `while game` loop, you should check collision only once. And repeat it in next loops. So you should use `if` instead of `while`.

But this needs also other changes. You need `else:` to move back when it detects a collision and it should also select a new direction.

```
#GHOST MOVE
move_list = ['right', 'left', 'up', 'down']
move_chise = random.choice(move_list)  # first direction at start.

while game:
    for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                exit()

    if move_chise == 'right':
        if not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.x += speed
        else:
            ghost.rect.x -= 2
            move_chise = random.choice(move_list)
    elif move_chise == 'left':
        if not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.x -= speed
        else:
            ghost.rect.x += 2
            move_chise = random.choice(move_list)
    elif move_chise == 'up':
        if not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.y -= speed
        else:
            ghost.rect.y += 2
            move_chise = random.choice(move_list)
    elif move_chise == 'down':
        if not sprite.spritecollide(ghost, walls, False):
            ghost.rect.y += speed
        else:
            ghost.rect.y -= 2
            move_chise = random.choice(move_list)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code.

Instead images `jpg` I used `Surface()` filled with color red - This way everyone can simply copy and run it without images `jpg`.

I also changed:

- Lists which create walls and coins.
- In some places, I check `rect.bottom`, `rect.top` instead of `rect.y` and `rect.left`, `rect.right` instead of `rect.x`.
- In `blit()` I use `player.rect` instead of `(player.rect.x, player.rect.y)` .
- Added `Player.move()` and `Enemy.move()`.
- Created three ghosts.
- Jumped from left tunnel to right tunnel.
- All objects use `draw(window)` instead of `draw()`, `show()` or `draw_wall()`.
- All objects use `x,y,width,height` instead of `player_x`, `wall_x`, etc.
- Set color as tuple `(R,G,B)` instead of separated values `color1, color2, color3`.

```
import random
from pygame import *

class GameSprite(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y, width, height, speed):
        super().__init__()

        #img = image.load(image)
        img = Surface((1000, 1000))
        img.fill((255,0,0))
                               
        self.image = transform.scale(img, (width, height))
        
        self.speed = speed
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        
class Hero(GameSprite):
    def update(self):
        print('TODO: Update Hero')
        
    def move(self, keyPressed):
        side = None
        
        if keyPressed[K_LEFT] and self.rect.left > 5:
            self.rect.x -= self.speed
            if sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False):
                side = 'Right'
                self.rect.x += 2
                
        if keyPressed[K_RIGHT] and self.rect.right < win_width:
            self.rect.x += self.speed
            if sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False):
                side = 'Left'
                self.rect.x -= 2
                
        if keyPressed[K_UP] and self.rect.top > 5:
            self.rect.y -= self.speed
            if sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False):
                side = 'Down'
                self.rect.y += 2
                
        if keyPressed[K_DOWN] and self.rect.bottom < win_height:
            self.rect.y += self.speed
            if sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False):
                side = 'Up'
                self.rect.y -= 2

        if side:
           print('Hero collision:', side)
                
        if self.rect.right > win_width-10 and 300 < self.rect.top < 330:
            self.rect.left = 10 

        elif self.rect.left < 10 and 300 < self.rect.top < 330:
            self.rect.right = win_width-10
                
class Enemy(GameSprite):

    def __init__(self, image, x, y, width, height, speed):
        super().__init__(image, x, y, width, height, speed)
        
        self.move_list = ['right', 'left', 'up', 'down']

        self.direction = random.choice(self.move_list)

    def move(self):
        if self.direction == 'right':
            if not sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False):
                self.rect.x += speed
            else:
                self.rect.x -= 2
                self.direction = random.choice(self.move_list)
        elif self.direction == 'left':
            if not sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False):
                self.rect.x -= speed
            else:
                self.rect.x += 2
                self.direction = random.choice(self.move_list)
        elif self.direction == 'up':
            if not sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False):
                self.rect.y -= speed
            else:
                self.rect.y += 2
                self.direction = random.choice(self.move_list)
        elif self.direction == 'down':
            if not sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False):
                self.rect.y += speed
            else:
                self.rect.y -= 2
                self.direction = random.choice(self.move_list)
    
class Wall(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.color = color
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        self.image = Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# it keeps single coin so name `Coin` without `s` seems better        
class Coin(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        self.image = Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        

# --- main ---

win_height = 700
win_width = 700

init()  # pygame.init()       

window = display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
display.set_caption('Pacman Game')

#back = transform.scale(image.load('photo_2022-06-05_21-28-54.jpg'), (700, 700))
player = Hero('photo_2022-06-05_20-54-50.jpg', 10, 309, 15, 15, 2)
player.image.fill((0,255,0))

ghost_chise = Enemy('photo_2022-06-05_20-56-46.jpg', 350, 309, 20, 25, 2)
ghost_chise.image.fill((0,255,255))
ghost_other = Enemy('photo_2022-06-05_20-56-46.jpg', 350, 309, 20, 25, 2)
ghost_other.image.fill((255,255,0))
ghost_third = Enemy('photo_2022-06-05_20-56-46.jpg', 350, 309, 20, 25, 2)
ghost_third.image.fill((255,0,255))

walls = [
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 0, 700, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 20, 31, 210), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 200, 145, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 115, 200, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 270, 145, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 670, 20, 31, 210), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 556, 200, 145, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 556, 200, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 556, 270, 150, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 335, 0, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 187, 70, 110, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 406, 70, 110, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 187, 470, 110, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 406, 470, 110, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 190, 335, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 485, 335, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 670, 700, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 400, 31, 280), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 400, 145, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 115, 340, 31, 70), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 0, 334, 145, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 670, 400, 31, 280), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 556, 340, 31, 70), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 556, 334, 145, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 556, 400, 150, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 16, 531, 60, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 624, 531, 60, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 260, 340, 180, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 260, 135, 180, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 260, 531, 180, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 260, 400, 180, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 190, 135, 31, 160), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 335, 135, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 335, 405, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 335, 542, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 190, 535, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 485, 535, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 485, 135, 31, 160), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 75, 70, 70, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 75, 133, 70, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 555, 70, 70, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 555, 133, 70, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 555, 470, 70, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 75, 470, 70, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 115, 470, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 555, 470, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 75, 600, 220, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 405, 600, 220, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 215, 200, 85, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 405, 200, 85, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 260, 270, 30, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 410, 270, 30, 31), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 260, 275, 31, 95), 
    Wall( (169,169,169), 410, 275, 31, 95), 
]

coins = sprite.Group()

coins.add([
    Coin( (255,255,0), 130, 309, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 240, 309, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 340, 250, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 460, 309, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 570, 309, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 240, 180, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 460, 180, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 310, 111, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 390, 111, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 60, 180, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 640, 180, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 60, 50, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 640, 50, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 160, 409, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 240, 380, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 340, 380, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 460, 380, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 530, 409, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 460, 450, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 240, 450, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 390, 450, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 310, 450, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 630, 450, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 50, 450, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 600, 520, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 90, 520, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 530, 570, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 160, 570, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 60, 640, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 640, 640, 5, 5), 
    Coin( (255,255,0), 350, 640, 5, 5), 
])

finish = False
game = True

coins_count = 0
count = 0
speed = 1

clock = time.Clock()

while game:

    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    # GHOSTS
    ghost_chise.move()
    ghost_other.move()            
    ghost_third.move()
    
    # PACMAN
    keyPressed = key.get_pressed()
    
    player.move(keyPressed)

    if sprite.spritecollide(player, coins, True):
        coins_count += 10
    
    # UPDATE SCREEN    
    if not finish:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        
        for w in walls:
            w.draw(window)
            
        coins.draw(window)
        
        player.draw(window)
        
        ghost_chise.draw(window)
        ghost_other.draw(window)
        ghost_third.draw(window)

        display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

    if finish:
        game = False
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to the while loop, the sprites are moving as much as downwards as they can. This does make the speed not matter, as they do move that speed untill they can't move anymore each frame. Therefore, you should remove the while loops and place its contents directly in the if statement they're in.